# How to apply conditional formatting to part of a string in one cell in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm not sure this is possible but thought it was worth the ask:

I'm trying to use conditional formatting to change the colour of part of a string contained within a single cell in google sheets. I would like the end result to look like cell A1 in the attatched image.

[image: 5 values coloured seperately in one cell]

Ideally, this would be done based on the corresponding values in a table (again see image) - however I would settle for just knowing if it's possible to apply two kinds of formatting to different parts of a cell like this!

I have tried a few things, but don't really know where to start.

I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is something that can be done on Google sheets as of right now. Conditional formatting applies to cells, not text, so attempting to combine different formatting to different texts within a cell would likely need to be manual.